# How do I disable stored procedure viewing rights for a specific Pervasive user account?

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I would like to disable a Pervasive user account from viewing a stored procedure which contains sensitive algorithms.

I have been unable to find anything on the Action PSQL documentation page (http://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html). I know that for MSSQL this can be done by using a DENY e.g.

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.stored_procedure TO User
```

Is there an equivalent Pervasive SQL command which I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of anyway to prevent viewing the Stored Procedures.  Views are protected but Triggers, Functions, and Stored Procedures aren't protected from the "Edit" option in the Pervasive Control Center (PCC).  Even if they were protected, selecting from the system tables (for stored procedures, `X$PROC`)was still available from the PCC.  I was even able to execute a User Defined Function when the group the user was logged in with had no rights at all.  The command to remove rights is [REVOKE](http://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/sqlref%2Fsqlref.REVOKE.htm%23).  In V2 Metadata databases, there is a permission to grant/revoke rights to alter a procedure but it doesn't prevent viewing it.
Contacting Actian might be your best source for help.